# Is there any good way retrieve data without rs.getString and save in .xls or .csv format?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

Iam working on one application where i want to download table in .xls format,Table is downloading in .xls format but i have to give column name in while(rs.next()) condition which is i dont want,I want without specifying column name data should download base on st.executeQuery();  is there anyway? here i'm pasting my code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Download_excel.jsp">
          <table border="1">
              <tr>
                  <td>FILE_NAME</td>
                  <td>FILE_UPLOAD_DATE</td>
                  <td>POLICY_NO</td>
                  <td> ENDORSEMENT_NO</td>
                  <td> GP_EBAO</td>
                  <td> TOL_PRM</td>
                  <td> PRODUCT_NAME</td>
                  <td> POLICY_NUMBER</td>
                  <td> GP_OF</td>
                  <td>DIFF</td>

              </tr>
              <%


                  String txtfilename=request.getParameter("txtfilename");
                  String btnsubmit=request.getParameter("btnsubmit");
                     if(txtfilename==null ||txtfilename.trim().isEmpty())
       {
           out.println("<html><body><script type=\"text/javascript\">"); 
            out.println("confirm('first name field cannot be blank');"); 
            out.println("location='xlsUpload.html';");
            out.println("</script></body></html>"); 

       }
                     else
                          if(btnsubmit!=null)
                          {

                               response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+txtfilename+".xls");
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.115.213:1821:db","xe","se");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from DYNAMIC_INSERT where file_name='"+txtfilename+"'");

        while(rs.next())
        {


              %>
              <tr>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("FILE_NAME")%></td>


              <td><%=rs.getString("FILE_UPLOAD_DATE")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("POLICY_NO")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("ENDORSEMENT_NO")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("GP_EBAO")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("TOL_PRM")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("PRODUCT_NAME")%></td>

                  <td><%=rs.getString("POLICY_NUMBER")%></td>
                         <td><%=rs.getString("GP_OF")%></td>
                         <td><%=rs.getString("DIFF")%></td>
              </tr>

              <%
              }
}
              %>
          </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here i'm tried below code but retrieve only column names not data

```
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        int numOfCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for(int i = 1; i <= numOfCols; i++)
        {
        %>
        <tr>
        <td>
           <%=rsmd.getColumnName(i))%>;
            </td>
            </tr>

        <%  
        }
        %>
```

Comment: If you want to output all columns and all columns contain String, you can use `<%=rs.getString(i)%>` in your try-code.

Comment: @Holger: no is not worked

Comment: rs.getString(int idx) is a legal call if idx is a legal column index. "Not working" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You are half way there already.
You can use ResultSetMetaData for that.

And then call rs.getString passing the column index.
See -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numOfCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while(rs.next()) {
  for(int i = 1; i <= numOfCols; i++) {
    <%=rs.getString(i)%>
  }
}
```